# Applications of Conio.h in embedded C

Tags: c, embedded

I have used conio.h library file in C and CPP for functions like clrscr() and getch(). What else is it used for in embedded C ?

Conio.h functions

clrscr
delline
getch
getche
gotoxy
kbhit
wherex
wherey
textcolor
textbackground

Comment: This is too broad, and a "list"-question. What's your actual problem with the file?

Comment: I have just started learning embedded systems coding using C. So far I have not used conio.h. I just wanted to know some common examples of how it is used in embedded C.

Comment: Why would one use it? It's a non-standard MS-DOS relic. I've personally never used it.

Comment: conio.h is not part of standard C, and was used for console io in MS-DOS, why on earth would anyone be using it for modern embedded systems development?

Comment: @Colin: because of schools that are still stuck in 90s turbo c...

Comment: The only remaining systems where that would be useful are the PC 104 family of boards. These "stack" together to make a semi-legacy device. Even so, it's nearly impossible to find one anymore that supports the ISA bus, as chipsets supporting PCI is about all that is universally available these days and the "south bridge" is all but forgotten now. I don't know of anyone still making a PCI-to-ISA bridge IC, anymore. (ISA DMA is fundamentally incompatible with PCI transactions, due to timing issues, and a source of bugs and difficulties no one wants to worry about now. For example.)

Answer (score 2):

> I have used conio.h library file in C and CPP for functions like clrscr() and getch(). What **else** is it used for in embedded C ?

(my emphasis above)

It's not clear why you asked what **else** is it used for. Perhaps you meant "what is it used for" and the answer is: There is no typical usage for that file on embedded systems.

In the embedded systems world, the designs are customised to specific purposes, and you cannot assume that code and header files related to things like screen output, would be applicable to a given embedded system - although such a system could be designed, if you really wanted to.

There is no *guaranteed standard* hardware across all embedded systems † - unlike DOS PCs where that header file is typically used, since the PC BIOS does present standard API calls for things like video and keyboard I/O (e.g. INT 10h for video and INT 16h for keyboard; DOS also presents additional relevant API calls through INT 21h). Some more background info is given in this [conio.h entry in Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conio.h).

In other words, there is no guarantee of any "screen" existing in an embedded system, for `clrscr()` to actually have any effect. The same applies to the other functions e.g. there is no guarantee of a keyboard being present on an embedded system, where `getch()` would be useful.

Summary: `conio.h` assumes that PC hardware and/or DOS is being used, which will not be true of most embedded systems as explained above, *unless* a whole PC (or customised hardware which is compatible with PC software) is being used as an embedded system (e.g. in some industrial applications).

---

† With the possible exception of a serial port, which is very common but still not universal.

Comment: Thank you. You are right. I only just made the transition from C coding to embedded systems.